# How to Initialize Date Correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have these line of codes:

```
Dim tmpDate as Date
tmpDate = “01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM”
MsgBox tmpDate
tmpDate = “01/01/2000 12:00:00 PM”
MsgBox tmpDate
```

Output:

```
01/1/2000
01/1/2000 12:00:00 PM
```

Why on the first date, it doesn’t have time on it?

I tried to make it 00:00:00 but still unable to get 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: It doesn't need it. If you want to force the time, format the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates are stored as numeric values (number of days since 1899-31-12 I think).

For that reason,

`01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM` is stored as `36526`

`01/01/2000 12:00:00 PM` is stored as `36526.5` (`0.5` of a day later)

Just like we would wouldn't write `36526.0` when `36526` suffices, Excel doesn't bother to display the `.0` either. So you don't see the `12:00:00` AM element.

To see the full date and time, just like if you wanted to see `36526.0` - you need to format the output to display it per your requirement:

```
Dim tmpDate As Date
tmpDate = "01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM"
MsgBox Format(tmpDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
tmpDate = "01/01/2000 12:00:00 PM"
MsgBox Format(tmpDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Output:

```
01/01/2000 00:00:00
01/01/2000 12:00:00
```

(I don't know your regional settings, so you may want to alter the formatting string to your requirement.)

Comment: Strictly speaking 01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM is stored as 36526.0 - that is the point, and yes some of us would write 36526.0 to avoid confusion.

Comment: Using the default date system in Microsoft Excel for Windows, the date_text argument must represent a date between January 1, 1900 and December 31, 9999. (the number of days since January 1, 1900)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252
Also see -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system
As far as I know dates before 1900 are represented as negative numbers

Answer (score 3):

Dates (in VBA and in Excel) are stored internally as Double. The integer part of that double defines the date (counting number of days since 1/1/1900), while the fraction part represents the time: 0 means 12am, 0.25 = 6am, 0.5 = 12pm...). You can show that by printing the value as Double:

```
Dim tmpDate As Date
tmpDate = "01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM"
Debug.Print CDbl(tmpDate)
tmpDate = "01/01/2000 12:00:00 PM"
Debug.Print CDbl(tmpDate)

>>36526 
>>36526.5
```

As the type `Date` is used for both dates and times, VBA assumes that you have only a Date without time when you print it and omits the 12:00am-part. However, you can use the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function to change how the date is printed:

```
Dim tmpDate As Date
tmpDate = "01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM"
Debug.Print Format(tmpDate, "dd/mm/yyyy h:nn am/pm")
tmpDate = "01/01/2000 12:00:00 PM"
Debug.Print Format(tmpDate, "dd/mm/yyyy h:nn am/pm")

>>01.01.2000 12:00 am
>>01.01.2000 12:00 pm
```

Note that this is only a matter of *displaying* (formatting) the date, similar to setting the number format to a cell: The *value* of the date doesn't change, only the way you show it to the world.